# Determining signal strength in nRF24L01

Tags: arduino

I learned that Tmrh20's [library](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/master/RF24.h) for nRF24L01 provides us to print out "strong signal" if some threshold passed and "weak signal" if not.

```
bool goodSignal = radio.testRPD();
if(radio.available()){
Serial.println(goodSignal ? "Strong signal > 64dBm : "Weak signal < 64dBm");
radio.read(0,0);
```

That means we are actually able to determine the signal strength, for example -40dBm in order to do this comparison. So I need this value.
Any way to get this value?

Answer (score 1):

No, not directly.

In the original version of the Nrf24L01 specification, there is a bit, labeled RD, in register 09. That bit triggers if the incoming signal is greater than -64dB, cleared otherwise.  In version 2 of the spec, they changed the name to carrier detect.  It has the same threshold, but suggests pulling the device in receive mode and checking the bit.
Long story short, you can glean some information from the RD/CD bit(register 09) in conjunction with register 08, which contains the number of packets lost and the number of retransmits.